# vector<std::pair> Vs. 2 X vector<T>

Tags: c++, c++11

During runtime, given a number N (unsigned long int), I have to take 2*N inputs from the user. I have to store them. The task is done and the question is not about how to do it. I was experimenting with the code and how to make it more standard and efficient. So, there are following three options among others :

1. Construct two `std::vector<unsigned long int>` vectors, to store
   first and second element respectively of each pair.
2. Construct one `std::vector<unsigned long int>` vector of length 2*N.
3. Construct one `std::vector<std::pair<unsigned long int, unsigned long int> >`.

So, I wrote this little program to see the execution speeds.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<utility>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  const unsigned long int len{10^10};
  clock_t time1{clock()};
  for(auto i = 1;i<100000;++i)
  vector<unsigned long int>veca(2*len);
  //  vector<unsigned long int>vecb(len);                                                                                                        
  cout<<((double)(clock()-time1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)/(100000)<<endl;
  time1 = clock();
  typedef pair<unsigned long int, unsigned long int> NumberPair;
  for(auto i = 1; i<100000;++i)
    vector<NumberPair>vecu(len);
  cout<<((double)(clock()-time1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)/(100000)<<endl;
  return 1;
}
```

The output was

- 2.3658e-07
- 3.1432e-07

If instead of 10, a length of 10^10 is used, then, the output is

- 1.6742e-07
- 8.591e-08

Thus it is better to go for choice 3 than choice 2.

Similarly by changing the code, it can be shown that choice 3 is better than choice 1.

Infact, the experiments show that choice 3 is better than choice 2 which is better than choice 1

Moreover the change in execution times, is lesser for small data sizes and more for large data sizes.

What is the explanation of such a behavior ?

Comment: The explanation is that you performed poor bench-marking. To get any meaningful result, run the same code in a loop, and time that. Then you can divide the total time by the repetition number to get an average time. That should eliminate the timing overhead, anyway

Comment: @StoryTeller I have updated the code for average time. The results are consistent.

Comment: `10^10` is zero.

Comment: Just to clarify @aschepler's point: C/C++ doesn't have an exponentiation operator. `^` is the [bitwise XOR operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR). The bitwise XOR of any number with itself is, by definition, 0.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to assess the relative performances of the various approaches with a small value of `N`. Hence, I wouldn't give much weight to the first set of numbers.

The second set of numbers are indicative of a trend.

When you construct a vector of type

```
std::vector<std::pair<unsigned long int, unsigned long int> >
```

the number of elements is half of the vector constructed with the type

```
std::vector<unsigned long int>
```

I'm going to guess that the difference in performance is caused by the fact that it takes `2*N` iterations on the elements of the vector to fill the data in the second case while it takes half the number of iterations on the elements of the vector to fill the data in the first case.